# Need little help on React hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I try to make a todo list with React and Redux Toolkit. In handleSubmit function to add item on list, my setText somehow not set the value to empty string.
Here are my full code on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-bqmjz1?file=components%2FTodoForm.tsx

```
const TodoForm = (): JSX.Element => {
  //Input value
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  //setText not working
  const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (text.trim().length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    dispatch(addItem({ title: text }));
    setText('');
  };

  return (
    <form className="container-fluid" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="input-group">
        <input
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter the value..."
          onChange={(e: { target: HTMLInputElement }) =>
            setText(e.target.value)
          }
        />
        {/* Submit button */}
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close! You just missed the value prop on the input:

`value={text}`

```
const TodoForm = (): JSX.Element => {
  //Input value
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  //setText not working
  const handleSubmit = (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (text.trim().length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    dispatch(addItem({ title: text }));
    setText('');
  };

  return (
    <form className="container-fluid" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="input-group">
        <input
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter the value..."
          value={text}
          onChange={(e: { target: HTMLInputElement }) =>
            setText(e.target.value)
          }
        />
        {/* Submit button */}
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot! I forgot that :V

Comment: No worries! You've introduced me to stackblitz, so cheers! :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well the input does not become empty when you click on the add button. To do that you just have to add `value={text}` in your input

```
<input
    className="form-control"
    placeholder="Enter the value..."
    value={text}
    onChange={(e: { target: HTMLInputElement }) =>
    setText(e.target.value)
    }
/>
```

Comment: it's worked!, thanks

Comment: No problem mate, do not hesitate if you need more help ;)